# Could LLVM decide the execution order of Machine Function Pass ? The code generated by my Pass has been messed up by the optimisation

Tags: optimization, backend, llvm

I am new to LLVM backend. What I am trying to do is inserting several register loading and storing between different instructions. So I create a machine function pass to do this job. When I disable the optimisation via -O0, everything works fine.

However, when I enable the optimisation, I found that the code has been optimised in a wrong way. For example, some labels of -O0 code has been kept.
For example it still keeps jl label1; while label1 is not exist in -O3 code.

I am trying to figure out a way to bypass it. My thought is that maybe we can decide the execution order of Machine Function Pass and I could then run my Pass at the very end. Or maybe there is other ways bypass it?

I have been searching it for a while, but I didn't find anything useful.

Thanks for your kind helps !

Comment: You might try the -print-after-all argument, which prints the IR after each pass. That'll tell you which pass removes the instructions, which should help you with finding out why it happens and might help you find a way to... well, to secure world peace.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot ! LLVM has too many APIs and command options !

Comment: You're using it precisely because it has all that, aren't you?

Comment: Yea. Finding APIs is much better than making those by ourselves.